# Some clients(users) cannot invoke the API. (both publisher, devportal on tryout tab)

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Most users can run API call tests in publisher or devportal.
However, sometimes when some USER executes "Execute", the following message appears and does not work.

PUBLISHER TRYOUT
[error message]
Failed to fetech
Possible Reason :  CORS, NETWORK Failure, URL schem must be "http" or "https" for CORS request

DEVPORTAL TRYOUT
[error message]
TypeError: Failed to fetch

Do you know any solution?

[image: devportal]

[image: publisher]

Comment: This is due to CORS restriction of the Browsers. Can you copy and share the Console traces related to CORS error by opening the Inspect > Console in the Browser? Share the traces captured for both Publisher and Devportal in the question.

Comment: @Athiththan, i have attached the images  (first is a devportal UI, second image is a publisher UI)

Comment: The Console trace of the Devportal mentions 'ERR_CONNECTION_RESET', which means, that the API Manager was not able to communicate with the actual Backend API endpoint. Can you check whether the API is accessible by making a direct invocation using a curl or Postman? Also, you can try out few steps mentioned in [here](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/hosting/technical-matters/err-connection-reset/)

Comment: Hope you noticed step 3.3 in https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/get-started/api-manager-quick-start-guide/

Comment: In postman it worked fine. And it didn't work in chrome only, it worked in firefox. Perhaps we can go to the link you shared and delete the history, or proceed with a few things. Thanks @Athiththan

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure your deployment.toml with the CORS settings:

```
[apim.cors]
enable = true
allow_origins = "*"
allow_methods = ["GET","PUT","POST","DELETE","PATCH","OPTIONS"]
allow_headers = ["authorization","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Content-Type","SOAPAction","apikey", "testKey","internal-key"]
allow_credentials = false
```

Adjust that for your scenario, because this is the way to allow all origins.

source: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/advanced-topics/enabling-cors-for-apis/#enabling-cors-globally

Comment: let me try~  Thanks.